# ggplot2: Use %+% to plot new data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm hitting a snag when I try to use the `%+%` operator to redo an existing plot with new data.  My code looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ending=now()+hours(0:5), actual=runif(6), pred=runif(6))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=ending)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=actual, color='Actual')) +
  geom_line(aes(y=pred, color='Predicted')) +
  ylab('Faults') +
  scale_color_manual('Values', c("Predicted"="red", "Actual"="black"))
p
```

That works fine.  But when I try to substitute a new `df`, I hit errors:

```
p1 %+% df
Error in bl1$get_call : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, immediately after I post, I find the answer - it's not `ggplot2`'s `%+%` operator.  Another namespace collision.  The `mboost` package also provides a `%+%` operator.

I "solved" this by doing `detach(package:mboost)`.  I could also solve it by doing something like

```
replot <- get('%+%', 'package:ggplot2')
replot(p, df)
```

A solution to avoiding the namespace collision would be best, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Best I can come up with is `ggplot2::\`%+%\`(p, df)`, but I don't know how to combine specifying a infix binary operator and a namespace qualification.

Comment: Can infix binary operators be methods?  That might help solve the namespace collision, maybe, possibly.

Comment: If you don't use mboost's %+%, you can add \`%+%\` <- ggplot2::\`%+%\` to your RProfile to permanently alias it.

Answer (score 2):

You can reassign infix operators to infix operators, but I don't think you can then turn them back into regular functions without special effort. Try this instead:

```
 `%new+%` <- ggplot2::`%+%`
```

.... and use it as `p %+% df`, rather than as `%+%(a,b)`